# Bash script image processing with im2dcm

Tags: linux, bash, unix, image-processing

I have a tool in Linux called img2dcm to convert from jpg to DICOM (dcm) format as follows:
img2dcm image-001.jpg image-001.dcm
(I've already tried to do use a python based script but it doesn't works...)

I have 100 images and doing it by hand would be a nightmare...

I'm wondering if is possible to do a Bash script with a for loop i:1:100 to convert each image-i.jpg ? (notice that the couldn't be image-1 should be image image-001, 002...010..020..099 until 100...).

Thank you very much in advance... .

Comment: You should provide some code of what you tried so far

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you very much for your soon response!
I also fixed it with this... So no matters the number of files :)... .

## !/bin/bash

```
    for i in $( ls ); do
        a=${i%%.*}
    
    echo $a.jpg
    img2dcm $a.jpg $a.dcm
    done
```

Thank you again!.

Answer (score 4):

Here's an example:

```
for i in {1..100}
do j=$(printf "%03d" $i)
   img2dcm image-$j.jpg image-$j.dcm
done
```